# Subscribe to a topic in MQTT using WPF

Tags: c#, uwp, mqtt

I need to subscribe to different topic that have different sensor values. My issue with my code is when I click on the first button then the second button I lose the value of the first topic. Is there a way I can have one button that subscribe to different topics and display each topic message in a different textbox.

```
async void client_MqttMsgPublishReceivedAsync(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{

    string ReceivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        txtReceived.Text = ReceivedMessage;
        // Sensor1Reading.Text = txtReceived.Text ;
    });

}

private void Sensor1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string Topic1 = "sensor1";
    client.Subscribe(new string[] { Topic1 }, new byte[] { 2 }); 
    Sensor1Reading.Text = txtReceived.Text;
}

private void Sensor2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string Topic2 = "sensor2";
    client.Subscribe(new string[] { Topic2 }, new byte[] { 2 });
    Sensor2Reading.Text = txtReceived.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to subscribe the two topics at the same time since `Subscribe` method could pass a string array. Maybe you could try:

```
Topic1 = "sensor1";
Topic2 = "sensor2";
client.Subscribe(new string[] { Topic1, Topic2 }, new byte[] { 2,2 });
```

For displaying in different `TextBox`, it seems like you could know the message from which topic by `topic` parameter of `MqttMsgPublishEventArgs`. Please try this:

```
private async void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    string ReceivedMessage;
    if (e.Topic == Topic1)
    {
        ReceivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Sensor1Reading.Text = ReceivedMessage;
        });
    }
    else if (e.Topic == Topic2)
    {
        ReceivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Sensor2Reading.Text = ReceivedMessage;
        });
    }
}
```